# SQL Server : extracting specific strings and then joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, substring, extract

I am fairly new to SQL Server.

I have been given two tables to join in order to get the matches between two tables: `PRODUCT` and `CUSTOMERS`.

The first table (`PRODUCT`) has 14 columns, whereas the second table (`CUSTOMERS`) has 5 columns. Having a quickly look upon the data it appears that is one column which is the relationship between the two tables: `NAMES1` in `PRODUCT` and `NAMES2` in `CUSTOMERS`.

However, in order to be able to join the tables I need to extract some strings from different columns in the table CUSTOMERS first as something has messed up when someone else imported the data into SQL. The name I need in column NAMES2 in table CUSTOMERS is the last substring of that string (James in the example below) and then the rest of the name continues into the column to the right (ID) until the word "Alias" appears.

| NAMES2 | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2247 50% James | McCarthy Petersson Alias: James ","200874741", |

So, I need to extract the last string of the column NAMES2 and everything before "Alias" in the ID column (James McCarthy Petersson) and then inner join that column NAMES1 in PRODUCT table.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: That's a pretty bad table design. Can you fix it or do you have to work with what you've got?

Comment: One example is not sufficient for analyzing your data and deciding on an approach to isolate the identifying fragments of related information. It seems you want to join on "James" in this particular example - so is the pattern represented by these particular values consistent?

Comment: Now that I look at it, is this the result of an import gone bad and that someone did not divide the "fields" correctly and accidentally chopped up the name between 2 separate columns? For that matter, why would a person's name be found in a PRODUCT table?  Something seems seriously messed up here.

Comment: It might be. And yes, somethings has seriously messed up here and I need to work with this. I suppose it should be possible?

Answer (score 1):

One method you could use is is `string_split()` to find the last "word" in each string:

```
with p as
      select p.*, s.value as p_name
      from product p cross apply
           (select top (1) s.value
            from string_split(p.names1, ' ') s
            where p.names1 like '% ' + s.value
           ) s
     ),
     c as (
      select c.*, s.value as c_name
      from customer c cross apply
           (select top (1) s.value
            from string_split(c.names2, ' ') s
            where c.names2 like '% ' + s.value
           ) s
     )
select . . .
from p join
     c
     on p.p_name = c.c_name;
```

There are other methods -- but SQL Server has pretty bad string processing capabilities.  You really should reconsider your data model, because something seems wrong with how the data is presented.

For instance, a relatively simple method with no subqueries uses the reverse of the name to match:

```
select . . .
from products p join
     customers c
     on right(p.name1, charindex(' ', reverse(p.name1) + ' ')) = 
        right(c.name2, chardindex(' ', reverse(c.name1) + ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

User below query ( it will ignore any leading (") before that number. in 'ad"dfk "01645"' this will ignore first (") since there is no number followed by it):

```
select * from product p inner join entities c
on p.numbers=cast(trim(substring(substring(c.id,patindex('%"[0-9]%',c.id)+1,len(c.id)),1,charindex('"',substring(c.id,patindex('%"[0-9]%',c.id)+1,len(c.id)))-1))  as float)
```

To match numbers from ID field of entities to numbers field of product:

```
select * from product p inner join entities c
on p.numbers=trim(substring(substring(c.id,charindex('"',c.id)+1,len(c.id)),1,charindex('"',substring(c.id,charindex('"',c.id)+1,len(c.id)))-1))
```

Please be sure that all the records satisfy this condition. And specially be aware of ' ' in the string. Please try this and let me know your feed-back.

```
      select * from product p inner join entities c on 
p.[NAMES1] = concat(trim(left(trim(c.[ID]),
(case when charindex(' Alias',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Alias',trim(c.[ID])) when charindex(' Also known as',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Also known as',trim(c.[ID])) end)))
 ,' ',trim(right(trim(c.NAMES2),charindex(' ',reverse(trim(c.NAMES2))))))
```

Add any substitute for ' Alias' in case statement:

```
    (case when charindex(' Alias',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Alias',trim(c.[ID])) when charindex(' Also known as',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Also known as',trim(c.[ID])) 
when charindex(' Good Alias',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Good Alias',trim(c.[ID]))end)
```

From you single row example it seems that you can do the same thing just by replacing 'Alias: ' with '' in id field

```
select * from PRODUCT p inner join CUSTOMER c on
p.NAMES1=replace(c.ID,'Alias: ','')
```

Comment: extremely sorry. Typo. Instead of 'on' I wrote 'where'. I have changed the answer.

Comment: There are values in ID without substring 'Alias'. So charindex('Alias',trim(c.[ID]))-1 is returning -1 which is a invalid parameter for left() . I have changed my answer to address this problem. Please let me know how many rows of data are there in both the tables?

Comment: Need to address every single exception. Time consuming but we can get there if there is no other alternative.

Comment: Have you considered replace() option? It will be faster if it satisfies the condition.

Comment: You can  provide me those three columns from both the table and I can give it a try if it's ok with you. But surely it won't match all the rows properly.

Comment: is it possible to share screen with teamviewer or anything else? or you can generate two csv files and mail me.

Comment: Names1 from product. Names2 and id from entities.

Comment: All I can do is to share the six kind of "Aliases" variations I see in the ID column and in other instances there is nothing other than a product ID number. I don't know if that is sufficient for you create a syntax?

Comment: Let's try to do that.

Comment: I have changed my answer to address 'Alias' and 'Also known as'.

Comment: Add condition in case statement like when charindex(' Good Alias',trim(c.[ID]))>0 then charindex(' Good Alias',trim(c.[ID]))

Comment: is there any other numbers in ID field?

Comment: Is there any other (") in the field?

Comment: If so then my new answer should work. But every rows have to have two (") having numbers in between.

Comment: Gotta sleep. Will knock you tomorrow. User the one with PATINDEX. Your effort and patience to solve this is really appreciable.

Comment: Have you tried explicit conversion. I am afraid that the data we are extracting contains characters other than numbers.

Comment: Added the conversion. It's simple cast(columnname as float). But I am afraid that data there are some values other than float in there. Please try and let me know.

Comment: @Pablo What's the final outcome? Please let me know whether you succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
--==== Easily Consumable sample data (take note)
DECLARE @t TABLE (NAMES2 VARCHAR(100), ID VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t VALUES 
  ('9999 10% Walter', 'White Alias: Heisenburg ","2021991010",'),
  ('2247 50% James', 'McCarthy Petersson Alias: James ","200874741",');

--==== Solution
SELECT tName = f2.tName
FROM        @t AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[a-zA-z]%', t.NAMES2),
                    CHARINDEX(' Alias:', t.ID))) AS f(Pos1, Pos2)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(t.Names2, f.Pos1, 100),' ',
                           SUBSTRING(t.ID, 1, f.Pos2)))) AS f2(tName)
--JOIN        dbo.thatOtherTable AS ot
--  ON        ot.tName = f2.tName
```

Note that the Join is commented out but should help. This, as is, returns:

```
tName
----------------------------
Walter White 
James McCarthy Petersson
```